# Azure GraphAPI getMemberGroups Bad Request error

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I am attempting to make the Azure Graph API call  getMemberGroups, however I am getting a "400 Bad Request" error in response.

According to the documentation [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#getMemberGroups], the following request should be :
[image]

I am using POSTMAN to make the request however I keep getting a "Request_BadRequest" error code.

My POST request is:

[image]
Where the red bar is the tenant ID and the blue bar is the object ID of the user.

My headers are:

[image]

My body is:

[image]

I keep getting the error message:

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "Invalid JSON. The value '------' is not a valid number."
        }
    }
}
```

I am not too sure why that is happening, does anyone have any clues?

Comment: The value '------' refers to which value? The error message indicates there might be invalid characters in that value, could you post it out?

Comment: That's what I'm unsure about, I've posted the entire query above. 
The POST request, the headers and the body is all I have!

Comment: What I mean is `the value '-----'` in the error message, what's that value?

Comment: The error message I posted above verbatim error message, I don't know what the '-----' actually refers to!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we are posting the `json` data, you shouldn't use the **form-data**. For the `application/json` type data, we should use the **raw** option to send the data.

Answer (score 0):

How to know the authorization token of the  Ad User

[image]

Comment: That is provided to you by the AD user, they need to do an OAuth login, when that is done the access token is returned to the redirect URI.